# How to confirm or stop navigation to other page in React ,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How to confirm navigation to other page in react-router . I am using browserHistory.push() method for changing the route and react-router version 3.0.5 . How to ask for confirmation from the user before navigating to other page. ?

I have tried using onBeforeUnload method but it only works for the page reload . Its not working if we are navigating using browserHistory of react-router

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use React Router's [preventing transition](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions).

Comment: I tried this but it's giving error in Prompt.js file that the this.context.router.history is not defined  .

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the function is only in React Router v4 or above.

Answer (score 0):

I myself figured out it using setRouteLeaveHook method

this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route,this.routerWillLeave.bind(this));

routerWillLeave(nextLocation) {
      return 'You have unsaved information, are you sure you want to leave this page'
  }